# AngularJS single controller, multiple $http.get requests

Tags: json, angularjs

I am looking forward to develop an AngularJS application and I am wondrering if i could use a Single controller to send multiple $http.get requests, each time to a different URL, depending on the template called.

Example:

App.js

```
  .state('app.grocery', {
    url: '/grocery',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/grocery.html',
        controller: 'MasterCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

 .state('app.beverages', {
    url: '/beverages',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/beverages.html',
        controller: 'MasterCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

In my Controller.js, i wish to first capture the templateURL being called and based on that set the $http.get URL.Suppose if the templateURL is templates/grocery.html, the $http.get URL would be "xyz.com/grocery.json" and if the templateURL is templates/beverages.html, the $http.get URL would be "xyz.com/beverages.json"

Answer (score 0):

You have to check which page name in controller like

```
.controller('MasterCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams,$state) 
{
    if($state.current.name==='grocery')
    {
        //call grocery $http.get() for grocery
    }
    else
    {
        //call beverages $http.get() for beverages
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set your `jsonName` in your state itself and use get that in your controller using `$state.current`, that will have `jsonName` property which will have the information you want.

**Code**

```
.state('app.grocery', {
    url: '/grocery',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/grocery.html',
        controller: 'MasterCtrl'
      }
    },
    jsonName: 'grocery'
})
.state('app.beverages', {
    url: '/beverages',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/beverages.html',
        controller: 'MasterCtrl'
      }
    },
    jsonName: 'beverages'
})
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('MasterCtrl', function($state, $scope, $http){

   //$state.current.jsonName will provide current json name
   $http.get('xyz.com/'+ $state.current.jsonName +'.json')
   .succcess(function(){
      //code when ajax success
   });

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can - The above answer by @Paresh is correct.

However, in my opinion you shouldn't do that. Your approach is so, perhaps due to that you don't like to have many files or controllers. But whatever the reason, having a separate controller will help you to have a small units of clear code each responsible for one type of action.

If you ever want to implement unit tests, or have lots of variations like the ones you asked for, or even to have complex logic: implementing it the way you are about to will take so many 'IF' logic blocks like this one everywhere.

And if you decide that you want to decide that 'grocery' should become 'grocery_main', it's going to be lots of 'find & replace' and if you miss a single one, you are going to have bugs in your code quite easily.

These are fundamentals in learning good coding styles. If you may and are interested in learning, I suggest you should go ahead and take my advice.

Hope this helps